# Category Product Page Not displaying pagination

Tags: magento-1.8, product, catalog, navigation, pagination

Something weird happened and now my magento category page is not showing pagination. I tried searching every where but my store is still not showing page navigation(pagination).

(Magento 1.8 on nginx-php-fpm)

Answer (score 4):

As you are having Sort By option that means you have `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>` in your list.phtml file.

Check in the catalog.xml whether you have called xml for pagination. The xml should be as below

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
     <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

Comment: yes i have already done that... you can see my page shows number of pages for the toolbar but only the navigation link.. next and page number are not shown

Comment: is this code in between block `<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>` ?

Comment: here is my catalog.xml : http://pastebin.com/v5q7zNTa

Comment: Catalog.xml seems fine... could  you please paste your list.phtml file... also have you made any changes in template?? are you using any theme??

Comment: here is my list.phtml... http://pastebin.com/di6WPYg3

Comment: it seems to be fine too... have you made any changes in templates or so??

Comment: no i havent made any changes.. kindly visit my product list and you can see that after using layered navigation the page show pagination. i think some bock is hindering the display.. iste link http://cartmydeal.com/sports-fitness-health/sports/badminton.html/

Comment: @AkshayDwivedi I can see the pagination on the bottom of your page.

Comment: visit this link http://cartmydeal.com/sports-fitness-health/sports/badminton.html/ pagination is shown after first time layered navigation is used (any event triggered)

Comment: i know its late, but the actual bug was, i accidentally copied the app folder inside app folder again (quite a serious issue). but thanks for the help

Comment: thanks... Please mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your list.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```